# Remove "comma" separator after last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
      elem = $(this);
      part = $(this).attr("data-part-name");
      //alert(part);
      selected_options = "";
      $('.' + part).each(function () {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            selected_options +=  $(this).attr("data-option-name") + ' <b>,</b> '
          }
        });
        $("#part_child_" + elem.attr("data-part-id")).html(selected_options);
    });
});
```

If you see I am adding a "comma" to selected options.
Now problem is it adds comma even after the last element.

How can I remove the last comma

Comment: Don't do string concatenation. Put everything in an array and use `join`.

Comment: See Arun p Johny's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map) will a perfect fit for this. Also you can filter the checked items using [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        var part = $(this).attr("data-part-name");
        //alert(part);
        var selected_options = $('.' + part).filter(':checked').map(function () {
            return '<b>' + $(this).attr("data-option-name") + '</b>'
        }).get();
        $("#part_child_" + elem.attr("data-part-id")).html(selected_options.join(', '));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of iteration to compare with length of parts element and do the decision whether a comma needs to be added or not.Modify the code to:

```
var totalparts=$('.' + part).length;
$('.' + part).each(function (i) {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
 selected_options +=  $(this).attr("data-option-name") + totalparts!=(i+1) ?' <b>,</b> ':'';
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
$("#part_child_" + elem.attr("data-part-id")).html(selected_options.replace(/[\<\>\,b\/\s]+$/,''));
```

Comment: may be you are using space before or after " <b>,</b> " . try this edited answer.

Comment: yes, works. thanks.. will go with Arun's answer though.. not so good with this pattern matching..

Answer (score 0):

Just remove last `,` substring from the string,

```
if(selected_options.length > 0){
  selected_options = selected_options.slice(0,-1)
}
$("#part_child_" + elem.attr("data-part-id")).html(selected_options);
```